# dataframe drop time values outside of range: seeking efficiency boost

Tags: pandas, database, dataframe, filtering

Need to exclude rows with `Time` outside of 9:30-16:00 (inclusive of 9:30 & 16:00).

```
            Symbol                Time    Open    High     Low   Close  Volume  LOD  Sessions
0         AEHR 2021-08-11 04:33:00    6.52    6.52    6.52    6.52     200  NaN       NaN
1         AEHR 2021-08-11 05:43:00    6.46    6.46    6.46    6.46     100  NaN       NaN
2         AEHR 2021-08-11 07:53:00    6.34    6.34    6.34    6.34     300  NaN       NaN
3         AEHR 2021-08-11 08:02:00    6.06    6.08    6.06    6.08     402  NaN       NaN
4         AEHR 2021-08-11 08:05:00    6.15    6.15    6.15    6.15     100  NaN       NaN
...        ...                 ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...  ...       ...
```

Output:

```
        Symbol                Time   Open   High    Low  Close  Volume  LOD  Sessions
0         AEHR 2019-09-23 09:31:00   1.42   1.42   1.42   1.42     200  NaN       NaN
1         AEHR 2019-09-23 09:43:00   1.35   1.35   1.34   1.34    6062  NaN       NaN
2         AEHR 2019-09-23 09:58:00   1.35   1.35   1.29   1.30    8665  NaN       NaN
3         AEHR 2019-09-23 09:59:00   1.32   1.32   1.32   1.32     100  NaN       NaN
4         AEHR 2019-09-23 10:00:00   1.35   1.35   1.35   1.35     400  NaN       NaN
...        ...                 ...    ...    ...    ...    ...     ...  ...       ...
```

Solution works but is **very** slow:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).dt.time

#Drop non-market time data (i.e outside 9:30-4:00)
df['after_open'] = df['time'] >= datetime.time(9, 30)
df['before_close'] = df['time'] <= datetime.time(16, 00)
filt = (df['after_open'] == False)
df = df.drop(index=df[filt].index)
filt2 = (df['before_close'] == False)
df = df.drop(index=df[filt2].index)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this two-liner:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
df = df.loc[df['Time'].ge("09:30:00") & df['Time'].le("16:00:00")]
```

---

```
print(df)
```